# Excel sheets are marked as group after going through script

Tags: python, excel

after my script does some work with excel file, sheets he was working with remain marked as a group and I can't find any reason why. Could anybody help?

My code is pretty long, so I'll only share some parts:

```
import ...

wbName = 'Kaprosinec2020.xlsx'

df2 = pd.read_excel(wbName, sheet_name='Kalibrace')
df4 = pd.read_excel(wbName, sheet_name='Vypocet Ka')

# modifies dataframes df2 and df4 (to simplyfy this, I let them both under same names here, original script renames them of course after he make those changes...)

book = load_workbook(wbName)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(wbName, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df2.to_excel(writer, 'Kalibrace', index=False, header=None, startcol=0, startrow=1)
df4.to_excel(writer, 'Vypocet Ka', index=False, header=None, startcol=9, startrow=3)
writer.save()
writer.close()

# now I used diferent type of writer, because I couldn't find a way to do so with the previous one...
# don't laugh at me, still a beginner trying to help myself any way nessesary... :)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(wbName)
wb.active = 1   # 'Kalibrace' is now an active sheet
ws = wb.active

# does some stuff...

wb.active = 0   # 'Vypocet Ka' is now an active sheet
ws = wb.active

# does some stuff...

wb.save(wbName)
wb.close
```

Now when I open the result excel file, the two sheets 'Kalibrace' and 'Vypocet Ka' are marked as a group, so when I want to further modify them, I have to unmarke them first, a bit unconfortable - can the script do that for me?

I'm sharing a picture:
[picture of result excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdKVl.png)

UPDATE: Solved. :) Unmarking one of the active sheets with the following line does the trick.

```
wb['Kalibrace'].views.sheetView[0].tabSelected = False
```

Since I don't have enough reputation to do so by taging comment as useful, I'm thanking [Warcupine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11643528/warcupine) for the answer this way.

Comment: Thanks, realized that right after I posted this, should have the python tag now. :)

Comment: Pretty sure `wb.active` is also selecting the sheet, since you activate two of them they are both selected and grouped. Something like `wb['Kalibrace'].views.sheetView[0].tabSelected = False` Not tested though.

Comment: Huh.... not tested, yet works perfectly fine.. :D Thanks a lot for clarification. :)
I can't find any way to officially give you credit for the answer in comment, if you post it as answer, I'll tag it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `wb.active` will select a sheet without deselecting the current sheet. Two sheets selected together are grouped.

So if you just have the two sheets this should work:

```
wb['Kalibrace'].views.sheetView[0].tabSelected = False
```

If you are planning on using more than two you can deselect them all.

```
for sheet in wb:
    wb[sheet.title].views.sheetView[0].tabSelected = False
```